# Repo Permissions Detailed Report

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Am I missing something here for Azure Repo permissions detailed report straight from the GUI? I'm trying to audit all rep permissions and have the necessary permissions (Project Administrator). When clicking the GUI "Get Detailed Report" I receive the candid response that the job is queued and will be emailed to me.

I've yet to ever receive an e-mail on the report, status or that it's even been kicked off. I've checked spam filters and nothing. I validated with our organization owner that the feature has never worked for him either.

Is this something in preview or just out right broken?

Answer (score 0):

There have been inconsistent on permission report notification on Azure DevOps however, you may follow this option [Download permissions report for repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/download-permissions-report?view=azure-devops#download-report)

However, I'm using [Permission Report using REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&preserve-view=true) for audit/compliance works and it works.